# non-fragment lexer rule x can match the empty string

Tags: antlr4

What's wrong with the following antlr lexer?

I got an error

```
warning(146): MySQL.g4:5685:0: non-fragment lexer rule VERSION_COMMENT_TAIL can match the empty string
```

Attached source code

```
VERSION_COMMENT_TAIL:
{ VERSION_MATCHED == False }? // One level of block comment nesting is allowed for version comments.
    ((ML_COMMENT_HEAD MULTILINE_COMMENT) | . )*? ML_COMMENT_END { self.setType(MULTILINE_COMMENT); }
| { self.setType(VERSION_COMMENT); IN_VERSION_COMMENT = True; }
```

;

Comment: Cannot specify actions in fragments.

Comment: @GRosenberg updated question, I got another problem when I removed the `fragments` keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert my ANTLR3 grammar for MySQL to ANTLR4? Remove all the comment rules in the lexer and insert this instead:

```
// There are 3 types of block comments:
// /* ... */ - The standard multi line comment.
// /*! ... */ - A comment used to mask code for other clients. In MySQL the content is handled as normal code.
// /*!12345 ... */ - Same as the previous one except code is only used when the given number is a lower value
//                   than the current server version (specifying so the minimum server version the code can run with).
VERSION_COMMENT_START: ('/*!' DIGITS) (
  {checkVersion(getText())}? // Will set inVersionComment if the number matches.
  | .*? '*/'
) -> channel(HIDDEN)
;

// inVersionComment is a variable in the base lexer.
MYSQL_COMMENT_START: '/*!' { inVersionComment = true; setChannel(HIDDEN); };
VERSION_COMMENT_END: '*/' {inVersionComment}? { inVersionComment = false; setChannel(HIDDEN); };
BLOCK_COMMENT: '/*' ~[!] .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN);

POUND_COMMENT: '#' ~([\n\r])*  -> channel(HIDDEN);
DASHDASH_COMMENT: DOUBLE_DASH ([ \t] (~[\n\r])* | LINEBREAK | EOF) -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

You need a local `inVersionComment` member and a function `checkVersion()` in your lexer (I have it in the base lexer from which the generated lexer derives) which returns true or false, depending on whether the current server version is equal to or higher than the given version.

And for your question: you cannot have actions in alternatives. Actions can only appear at the end of an entire rule. This differs from ANTLR3.

Comment: Wow ... just one question, do you have the ANTLR4 version at hand?

Comment: I have, but I cannot publish it yet. It will appear with the next MySQL Workbench release later this year.

Comment: The ANTLR3 version does not work with `SElect`, so I converted all SYMBOLS to fragments, e.g `fragment Z:('z'|'Z');` and `SELECT_SYMBOL:       S E L E C T ;`, am I doing it right?

Comment: Yes, that's how I did it as well.

Comment: On line 1121, https://s9.postimg.io/dkxh9xa0f/123.png You have a preceding `|` to the `CLOSE_SYMBOL`, was it a mistake? It will create an empty if branch. It's OK for C++ target, but won't work with python2. So I had that `|` removed, maybe you should do the same ...

Comment: Good find. This is a bug. Yes the first bar must be removed. Thx.

Comment: You already defined a `function_call` expression, why define `count_function` and `substring_function` in separate? And I didn't see you using it anywhere in `mysql-workbench-community-6.3.7-src`, hmm ...

Comment: This is not the right place to discuss things like that. Join the #workbench channel in IRC (e.g. via freenode.net) to get me for a live chat and I'll answer your question (CES time).